# Angular with {{}} directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to pass `{{string}}` to directive which gets this attribute from `$attrs` (not `$scope`)?

Here is some code:

controller:

```
...
scope.someId = "someId";
...
```

HTML:

```
<my-dir id="{{someId}}"></my-dir>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
   return {
      controller: function($attrs){
         console.log($attrs.id) //output: {{someId}}
      }
   }
})
```

What I want is that the output would be `someId` and not `{{someId}}`.

Comment: Did you mean you want to access the attributes in the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) function? Why do they need to be in the controller?

Comment: what's wrong with using a directive isolate scope and two way databinding (`scope: {someId: '=id'}`)

Comment: I am writing my app with the "as vm syntax" so I don't wont to use the link function. http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: $attrs.id.slice(2,-2)  
Don't flag my hack, please. ;)

Comment: That blog didn't say you couldn't define a link function on a directive. I'll keep searching about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to access the value from `$attrs` till the initial digest cycle is triggered. Once the digest cycle is triggered, you will be able to access it from the `$attrs`.

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
   return {
      controller: function($attrs){
         console.log($attrs.id) //output: {{someId}}
         $attrs.$observe('id', function (newVal, oldVal) {
             console.log(newVal, oldVal); // here you will be able to access the evaluated value. 
         });
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good and more professional way to do it.In angularjs there is an idea about scope field type:

There are 3 types of it.

1) string @

2) functional &

3) biDirectional =

This style is better.This link can help you.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object